# Check if nummer is correct

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and learning how to code with c#.
I have a question, but I can't figure it out.
This is my question.

So the user need to fill in a number. The number consists of 3 parts. The first part is a 3 digit number and the 2nd part is a 7 digit number, and the 3th part 2 digit number. This is how the number looks like: 001-2157858-72.
My application must check if my the number is correct, the number is only correct if I divide the first 2 part by 97 and the remainder is 
equal to part 3 (0012157858/97) = 125 338, r = 74 (not correct).  If not then the the number is wrong.

and I must use a methode.
This is my code, but I doesn't work and I didn't used a methode. Can someone please help me:

```
           string strPart1, strPart2, strPart3;
        string strNumber = "";


        Console.Write("Part 1: ");
        strPart1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Part 2: ");
        strPart2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Part 3: ");
        strPart3 = Console.ReadLine();

        strNumber = strPart1 + strPart2;


        Console.Write(strNumber);



        if (strNumber % 97 == strPart3 )
        {
            Console.Write("Corect number");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Wrong number");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Using a variable named `strSomething` with the modulo operator `%` should trigger a red light in your head -- strings do not have modulus (moduli?).

Comment: Wait you are doing strings with % modulus... look into converting or parsing it out to the numeric values.

Comment: *This is my code, but I doesn't work* isn't an helpful message

Comment: `strNumber = strPart1 + strPart2` is adding two strings together, resulting in concatnation, eg 0012157858. In order to add them numerically, I recommend looking into int.Parse

Comment: Yes, for example: 
part1: 001
part2: 2157858  = 0012157858.

Comment: Oh, I see, my bad. In that case, int.Parse on strNumber in order to do your modulus calculation.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I know, but I don't know how to convert them into int. I'm not allowed to use int.parse

Comment: @AlexF, I looked around but I found out that we haven't learned int.parse yet, so we aren't allowed to use it.

Comment: @Titan1655 tell your teacher. You "have to" use it

Comment: @Steve I need to use a methode/function like this: 
public static string  x(string y)

Comment: @Titan1655 sure...but inside your function you still needs to call int.parse unless you want to implement the parsing logic yourself

Comment: Trick your teacher and use Int32.TryParse();

Answer (score 0):

*Looks like you're trying to get us to make your homework.*

To clarify; what you mean is a [Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx). I suppose you want to write a method that will take 3 numbers (`int`s) as an input, and outputs `true` or `false` , representing if the number is correct or not.

To specify a function that can return a value, the return value must be the respective data type, in this case, `bool` (or `Boolean`). Let me assume you need the method to be public.

```
public bool NumberCorrect(int num1, int num2, int num3)
{
    // Your number logic goes here
    return (num1 + num2) % 97 == num3;
}
```

Next, you might've seen I used `int num1`. This is because the `int` datatype represents a (whole) number, an integer. Instead of making your numbers `string`s, try to parse them into `int`s, either via conversion, or `TryParse()`ing. *This is the first part your code fails at, because it will print "xxyyyy" instead of the sum of x and y.*

```
int number1, number2, number3;
bool ParseSuccess = System.Int32.TryParse(strPart1, number1);
//The line above will try to cast strPart1 to number 1 (as a number), and if it fails
//ParseSuccess will be false.
```

If you set everything up to your needs, calling

```
bool correct = NumberCorrect(number1, number2, number3);
Console.WriteLine(correct)
```

will give out the wanted result, and you **used a method**.